# Float left, float right aren't working

Tags: css, css-float

As you can see in my [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7bqS/):

```
.footer {
  background-image:url('/images/footer_bg.png') bottom repeat-x;
  height: 110px;
}
#footercontent {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height:110px;
}
#leftfoot {
  float: left;
  font-family:maven;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#rightfoot {
  float: right;
}
```

The `#rightfoot` right-floated divider isn't displaying on the right of the page, but instead alongside the `#leftfoot`, why is this?

Comment: Whats the width of leftfoot and rightfoot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your `#footercontent` is set to display as `table-cell` and has no parent width. Its width is currently controlled by the content within.

[image: Issue]

To resolve this, I've given it a parent divider which is set to display as `table` with 100% width:

```
<div id="footerContainer">
    <div id="footercontent">
        ...
    </div>
</div>

#footerContainer {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
```

To align the `#rightfoot` content to the right, I've simply given that a `text-align` of right:

```
#rightfoot {
    text-align:right;
}
```

[image: Final result]

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/u7bqS/12/)**.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but for some reason my footer_bg.png doesn't show up now..

Comment: There is no `.footer` divider in the HTML markup of the JSFiddle you provided, so I can't really help much. Is this definitely contained within a `<div class="footer">`?

Answer (score 4):

You gave no width, so they will extend until the browser's window and therefore, push one below.
To keep them side by side, declare a width.

For example, I declared:

```
#leftfoot, #rightfoot {
    width:50%;
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/u7bqS/11/)

*Note:* See that I declared the padding in the container instead of the floated div. If you leave on the floated div, the final width would be 50% of window+20px (which will make the right float to line break). If you want to keep padding on the floated divs, add `box-sizing:border-box;` (but it's not supported by old browsers so it's best to leave padding for the container)

Comment: why not just specify the width for `#footerContent`? That works too.

Comment: I've found in situations like this, it helps to use style="border-style:solid" when I want to check out what the individual elements are using.

Comment: @ByteBlast because will still be the same problem. See http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/u7bqS/9/ as example with `width:100%` on `#footerContent` only and reduce the width of the preview/result screen.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL I think I have misunderstood actually.

Comment: That didn't work for me. It makes rightfooter go onto a new line. Somehow it even messes up my nav...